# Creating Custom RegExpressions for MX:Validator - Explanation

Tags: apache-flex, validation, flex3

I'm been trying to validate Data in a Flex TextFiled, and I've encountered some Validator's include in the Flex Framework. But lets say i want to build a custom Validator with my own RegExpression.

Can somebody do me a simple example.

Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the RegExpValidator

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/validators/RegExpValidator.html

Comment: I looked in Adobe Docs for Costum Regular Expressions Validator and i did find one, but it as more complicated than this one. But i didn't saw this one, it works pretty well. Thanks.